# How to have separate .minecraft directories?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I want to download a Minecraft hack client, and I want to keep it separate from my main `.minecraft` folder because I play on Hypixel, and I don't want to get banned. How can I have separate directories?

Comment: Anyway Hypixel (or any servers) can't read your file system so as long as it's not active they won't know about it

Answer (score 1):

To set separate directories for Minecraft on the latest launcher, you can go to the Installations tab in the launcher, double-click the one with the hacked client, and change the game directory entry to whatever you want. To do this with a graphical file manager, you can use the browse button to bring up Finder, File Explorer, or Nautilus so you can manually select the appropriate folder.

Comment: the problem for me is i use sigma, and that just wants to be in your installations folder, so i cant really move it to .minecraft2

Comment: Move your Hypixel one to another one instead

Answer (score 0):

Sigma Client does not support custom loader directories. Its staff have stated before the only way to play with it (other than some convoluted techniques that I could find on Reddit) is using the official Minecraft launcher. It is not compatible with MultiMC or other multi-instance launchers. However, you will not be banned if you have a hacked client in your `.minecraft` directory, as long as it isn't the selected profile, there is no way for it to be detected.